# can some one post jms queue receiver examples in mule

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component

example --> here my scenario is assume i have 3 different flows (A.xml, b.xml, c.xml) each flow endpoint are jms receivers senders only. iam acheiving when A flow jms sender send msg to B flow it receives. but when b flow sends request to c flow by jms sender which is not receiving. because A flow depends on the output of C flow... what to do

Comment: i want to share my screen shots. but am unable to send. i need 10 reputation points to share 3 screenshots its saying.. can some one help me resolve my issue. am new to mule

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the scenario you explained, you can try some thing like below

[image]

In the above Mule flow, JMS inbound endpoint receives message from ActiveMQ and forwards message to other flows in parallel using scatter-gatther. Here flow references refers to flows in other configuration files (You can also use VM component to forward message to other flows)

Comment: thanks for the above one.. here my scenario is assume i have 3 different flows (A.xml, b.xml, c.xml) each flow endpoint are jms receivers senders only. iam acheiving when A flow jms sender send msg to B flow it receives. but when b flow sends request to c flow by jms sender which is not receiving. because A flow depends on the output of C flow... what to do